# Kotlin Generic abstract function

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, abstract-function

I have an abstract function, where I want to get any of my `Activity Presenters` in `BaseActivity`

```
protected abstract fun <T : BasePresenter<V>, V : BaseView> getPresenter(): T
```

So my function shoud accept only class that extends `BasePresenter` with view that extands `BaseView`

But when I implimment this function, I get an error

```
private lateinit var presenter: LauncherPresenter

override fun <T : BasePresenter<V>, V : BaseView> getPresenter(): T = presenter
```

> Type mismatch.
>
> Required: T
>
> Found: LauncherPresenter

I know this is stupid question, but I cant get where I am wrong.

Comment: What is the signature of `LauncherPresenter`?

Comment: please add more of your code if you want to get help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare generic in your function, because it already specified in your **BaseActivity** at the top.

Example your **BaseActivity**:

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : BasePresenter<V>, V : BaseView>() : 
AppCompatActivity(), BaseView {

  protected abstract fun getPresenter(): T

}
```

Where **T** specified at the top.

When you implement function in child of BaseActivity:

```
class LauncherActivity() : 
BaseActivity<LauncherPresenter<LauncherView>, LauncherView>(), LauncherView {

     private lateinit var presenter: LauncherPresenter

     //your override method
     protected override fun getPresenter(): LauncherPresenter = presenter

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your code but with  `Unchecked cast` like:

```
override fun <T : BasePresenter<V>, V : BaseView> getPresenter(): T = presenter as T
```

`LauncherPresenter` can't become `T` itself 
in the form that you use